# How to set avro content type on kafka producer with spring boot and spring cloud stream

Tags: avro, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to build a working example with avro message producer, kafka and avro consumer using spring boot, spring cloud stream schema registry, kafka binder. The following error occurs when consuming messages:

ERROR 7059 --- [afka-listener-1] o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder    : Unable to deserialize [io.igx.android.Sensor] using the contentType [application/x-java-object;type=io.igx.android.Sensor] java.lang.NullPointerException

I have
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.contentType=application/*+avro
on consumer side and
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.contentType=application/*+avro
on producer side.

Why is the consumer not seeing and using avro content type instead application/x-java-object.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the content type `application/*+avro` at the producer side. (note the * prefix). Once that is set for the producer, Can you confirm if you still need to specify the input contentType for the consumer. I think the consumer can deduce it based on the content type set by the producer.

Comment: I have now spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.contentType=application/*+avro at the producer side, and spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.contentType=application/*+avro at consumer side. Still same error: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: ...and if there is no arrays in avro schema I can consume message normally.

Comment: What happens when you set the content type as "spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.contentType=avro/bytes" ?

Answer (score 1):

Channel name was wrong. So problem was I was using 
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.contentType=application/*‌​+avro

instead of this

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.{MY CHANNEL NAME}.contentType=application/*‌​+avro.

When I changed {MY CHANNEL NAME} to the name that i used magic happened.

It works even if i did not specify content type on consumer side.

Also, I need to specify spring.cloud.stream.schemaRegistryClient.endpoint
if it's not default, like in my case, both, on producer and consumer side.